# New emulator in AVD manager gives "no longer exists as a device"

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I've been struggling with creating a new emulator with the AVD manager in the latest Android build tools. I can create a device profile and an emulator using it, but it immediately appears in the AVD manager as broken with an option to "Repair Device".

[image: AVD manager gives "Repair Device"]

Attempting to repair the device or wiping the data has no effect. This occurs on any kind of new emulator, including preset device profiles.

The exact error:

> Name: Android_Wear_Round_API_23
>
> CPU/ABI: Android Wear Intel Atom (x86)
>
> Path: C:\Users\Developer.android\avd\Android_Wear_Round_API_23.avd
>
> Error: User Android Wear Round no longer exists as a device

I'm using:

- Android Studio 2.2.1
- Android SDK tools 25.2.2
- Android SDK platform tools 24.0.4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem occurs when the AVD manager is looking for a hardware profile and can't find it, even though it exists. I have a feeling that this is caused by a bug in the latest tools that cause hardware profiles to be saved without a proper id, because profiles made a while ago are still working correctly (until you edit them). The following fixed it for me:

In your user profile folder, find `devices.xml` inside the `~/.android` folder, so on Windows you'd look for `C:\Users\Me\.android\devices.xml`.

Open the file and look for a device with the name that shows in the error message, in your case '**Android Wear Round**'. It'll look like this:

```
    <d:device>
        <d:name>Android Wear Round</d:name>
        ...
```

Duplicate the line with the name and change the tag to `d:id`, but keep the name, like so:

```
    <d:device>
        <d:name>Android Wear Round</d:name>
        <d:id>Android Wear Round</d:id>
        ...
```

Return to the AVD manager and hit refresh; the virtual device should be repaired now.

Comment: Woah, that worked like magic! How on earth did you figure that out?!

Comment: I was struggling with the same issue until I modified an existing, working profile and it broke because of the edit. The error message gave me an unexpected name, something like **wear_round** instead of the actual name of the profile (**Android Wear Round**). The `devices.xml` file seemed relevant, and Ctrl+F'ing through it I found that all working devices had an `<d:id>` and the broken ones didn't. More specifically because the file contained `<d:id>wear_square</d:id>` but did not contain `<d:id>wear_round</d:id>`.

Comment: Didn't work :( For context this is happening after moving the avd to an external hd

Comment: Interestingly, the problem for me was that the devices.xml file was somehow renamed to devices.xml.old - not by me

Comment: @kilkfoe i faced the same issue, did u find any solution?

Comment: @thekucays it's been a while and I don't remember (I guess my comment didn't have enough details since even I am not sure what I did now) - I'm guessing I renamed the file back to devices.xml

Answer (score 1):

Pre-req:  Set ANDROID_HOME to a location where valid android sdk is available , if on windows C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Recreate scenario:On running %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android.bat list avd, you should either observe "no-longer-exists as a device" or this would list valid devices.

Possibility 1:  devices.xml is missing in c:\users\.android\devices.xml is missing, invalid (cannot be parsed).  This can be restored from %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\lib\devices.xml

Possibility 2:  Device name on devices.xml and device name present in config.ini of emulator.
Open AVD manager, click on edit and copy Device name.
Update restored devices.xml with this name.

Ensure config.ini under c:\users\.android\avd\.avd\ has
identical entry as a value for the key
hw.device.name

Comment: very nice. this worked. might be worth mentioning that i had to close and re-open android studio. i thought exiting out of avd manager was enough, but it wasnt. +1

Answer (score 0):

All of a sudden some of my emulators showed this issue (5/9 emulators). It seems like those emulators that had issues were created using a custom hardware profile which was imported separately. And for some reason, the imported hardware profile was no longer available when I was trying to create a new emulator with those hardware profiles. So I reimported those Hardware profiles and all the emulator that showed error started working as usual.